# Impossible patterns in Idris

Tags: idris

I'm learning Idris and I got stuck on a very simple lemma that shows that some specific index is impossible for a data type. I've tried to use impossible patterns but Idris refuses them with the following error message:

```
RegExp.idr line 32 col 13:
hasEmptyZero prf is a valid case
```

The complete code piece is available in the following gist:

https://gist.github.com/rodrigogribeiro/f27f1f035e5a98f506ee

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've talk with people at freenode Idris community and they explained to me that
absurd pattern needs a explicit impossible case in order to detect that is really impossible. As an example:

```
hasEmptyZero : HasEmpty Zero -> Void
hasEmptyZero HasEps impossible
```

Here putting the constructor `HasEps` helps Idris to detect that it cannot be used to construct a value of type `HasEmpty Zero`. The complete (working) code is at the following gist:

https://gist.github.com/rodrigogribeiro/5b39048df1d9ddc083ec